# Every differentiable function is infinitely differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that every differentiable function is analytic. In Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable (1973), states that every analytic function is infinitely differentiable and has a power series expansion about each point of its domain. So does this imply that every differentiable function is (1) infinitely differentiable and (2) has a power series expansion about each point of its domain?

Comment: Not all differentiable functions are analytic...

Comment: All **complex differentiable** (on their whole domain) functions are analytic.

Comment: Ok, but he said a differentiable function is analytic, I must have interpreted in a wrong context.

Comment: Ah, well we do have the complex analysis tag going

Comment: Yes. Every function with a complex derivative at all points of its domain (an open set) is infinitely differentiable and analytic on that domain.

Comment: Well, [holomorphic functions are analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions) and they have power series expansions.